# Pyspark ml Creating Pipeline with catagorical & numerical columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

In order to fit a [RandomForestRegressor](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor) with both numerical and categorical columns, I want to create a clean Pipeline. I know I have to include OneHotEncoding to handle categorical data but I can't manage to format everything properly.

```
# Since I have either string or double column types, I can split my
# columns in two lists
cat_cols = [c for c, dtype in data.dtypes if dtype == 'string']
num_cols = [c for c in data.columns if c not in cat_cols]
```

In order to apply OneHotEncoding for categorical data, I need to apply StringIndexing first:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=cat_var, outputCol=cat_var+'_indexed', handleInvalid='keep') for cat_var in cat_cols]

# These two lists are here to lighten the code
cat_indexed = [cat_var+"_indexed" for cat_var in cat_cols]
cat_encoded = [cat_var+"_encoded" for cat_var in cat_cols]
```

Since 2.3, it's recommended to use [OneHotEncoderEstimator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoderEstimator).
Problem is no tutorial shows how to combine it with a list of StringIndexers and wrap it into a Pipeline.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoderEstimator
encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=cat_indexed, outputCols=cat_encoded)

# with version < 2.3 it would have been:
# encoders = [OneHotEncoder(inputCol=x, outputCol=y) for x,y in zip(cat_indexed, cat_encoded)]
```

Wrapping everything up with a [Pipeline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-pipeline.html):

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.features import VectorAssembler

# I have to get my numerical columns back:
cols_now = cat_encoded + num_cols
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=cols_now, outputCol='features')

# If my target variable had been a string, I would have apply StringIndexing for this also:
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='target_var', outpuCol='label')

# I need to concatenate a list of indexers, encoders, the vector assembler and my target_var
# What I would do if I had a list of encoders with the deprecated function OneHotEncoder:
tmp = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(indexers, encoders)]
tmp = [i for sublist in tmp for i in sublist]

tmp += [assembler, labelIndexer]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=tmp)
```

But:

- I have an encoder object and not an iterable so above code won't work
- My target var is numerical so should I just add it raw instead of labelIndexer ?

Comment: For random forest you need just StringIndexer not onehotencoder

Comment: Are you sure ? It'd simplify the problem.

Comment: Yes that is how tree algorithms work